# Implement REST API with Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

This is my Django model:

```
class M(models.Model):
    a = models.IntegerField()
    b = models.IntegerField()
```

This is the serializer:

```
class MSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = M
        fields = ['a', 'b']
```

I would like to be able to implement these REST APIs:

- `127.0.0.1:8000/m/` (GET list of all elements, POST new element)
- `127.0.0.1:8000/m/:id/` (GET details of element with id `id`)
- `127.0.0.1:8000/n/:a/m/` (GET all elements with a specific `a` field)

So far this is the view and urls that I implemented:

```
class MViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = M.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MSerializer
```

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'm', MViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

However, in this way the third use case is not working. How can I modify my code to make the third case work? I'd prefer to use as few lines of code as possible (i.e., I would like to use some Django built-in functionalities).

Comment: Didn't really get your 3rd case. GET all elements from what model? n or m? What's n there?

Answer (score 0):

Since it look like you want the 3rd endpoint on another root (possibly another app name `n`), I'll implement it is a standalone API view, and not as an action on a viewset (although both options are possible)

```py
class FilteredMListView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = MSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return M.objects.filter(a=self.kwargs["a"])
```

Then you register it to the router using:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path("n/<str:a>/m/", FilteredMListView.as_view())
]
```

Answer (score 0):

For your 3rd case, I would use a `ListAPIView`, overriding the `get_queryset` method to filter by the passed value for `a`. The idea is that when `get_queryset` method is invoked, and with as many other filters you'd like to implement, the condition for `a` is always present. Since the value for `a` will be in the url, it is mandatory, and you always have in in the view's kwargs. Would look like this:

urls.py

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'm', MViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('<a>/m', AValuesListApiView.as_view()
]
```

views.py

```
class AValuesListApiView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = M.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    return super().get_queryset().filter(score=self.kwargs["score"])
```